# Geometry problem with rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given right angled parallelepiped $ABCDA1B1C1D1$, with bases $ABCD$ and $A1B1C1D1$, which are squares with side $1$. if $\angle (B1C;D1A) = 60^\circ$
find the length of the surrounding edge (I'm not sure if this is the right term in English, those edges are $AA1,BB1,CC1,DD1$). Here is drawing:

[image]

I'm totally lost on this one.

Comment: Is the $60^\circ$ angle somehow between the red segments?  Or is it $B1CB$ or $B1CC1$?  You only give two points for each angle.  $\LaTeX$ hint:  to get a degree sign, use 60^\circ to get $60^\circ$

Comment: The angle between the red lines is $60^\circ$, this is how all angles are described in my textbook, my teach also uses this notation. But it's between the line AD1, and a line parallel to B1C, or vice verse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw $DA1$,which is parallel to $B1C$.  This does not define which angle is $60^\circ$.  If $E$ is the intersection of the new line and $AD1$, it could be $AEA1$ or $AED$  Either way you have the end face composed of two equilateral triangles and two $120^\circ-30^\circ-30^\circ$ triangles.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the given angle. If this was the given angle, the exercise is pretty simple.

Comment: OK, updated....